# Jenkins Pipeline Branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I thought this was a simple thing I wanted to do, but as I'm finding, nothing seems to be simple with Jenkins.

Basically all I want is:

- When developer pushes new code to a branch in BitBucket, I want a webhook to tell Jenkins to build that branch and report back the build status.

The webhook is working. However, no matter what I try, I can't get Jenkins to clone and checkout the commit of interest so that it can then use the Jenkinsfile on that commit to start the pipeline. I always get something along the lines of:

```
eneric Cause
GenericWebhookEnvironmentContributor
 Received:

{"pullRequest": {"fromRef": {"latestCommit": "f6be891de5c8d66023030d31e36a9fb9b01ef973"}}}


Contributing variables:

    commitId = f6be891de5c8d66023030d31e36a9fb9b01ef973


hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress --prune -- origin +refs/heads/${commitId}:refs/remotes/origin/${commitId}" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${commitId}

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2172)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1864)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:545)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:358)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:197)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:173)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:113)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:299)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

As you can see, the Git plugin does not seem to be resolving the Contributing variables? Yet this works in Freestyle projects?

Am I doing this wrong? What is the easiest way to simply use the Jenkinsfile in whatever commit was just pushed to run a pipeline?

P.S. I'm running the latest versions of everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up your error online and looks like there's a small change you need to make when you configure your pipeline:

There's a **lightweight checkout** checkbox that you need to uncheck.

Please checkout this git issue: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/507#issuecomment-299481993

and

https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/507#issuecomment-326014594

Comment: I know right, let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks!